# Using combineReducer with a immutable reducer & regular reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I'm trying to integrate [redux-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth) into my project, which uses immutables inside its reducers. My reducers currently don't use immutables, as I'm new to the environment. (I'll change them at some point I believe)

I wanted to first try to make the integration work. My app runs and I can see the auth reducer in my state tree; however, it says `Uncaught TypeError: e.get is not a function(anonymous function) @ combineReducers.js:107` in the console view and the auth app integration wouldn't work. Please let me know if anyone can help! Thanks.

```
export default combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  auth: authStateReducer,
  ....
});
```

combineReducers shown below:

```
function combineReducers(reducers) {
  var finalReducers = isImmutable(reducers) ? reducers : _immutable2['default'].fromJS(reducers);
  finalReducers = finalReducers.filter(function (v) {
    return typeof v === 'function';
  });
  var sanityError;

  try {
    assertReducerSanity(finalReducers);
  } catch (e) {
    sanityError = e;
  }

  var defaultState = finalReducers.map(function (r) {
    return undefined;
  });

  return function combination(state, action) {
    if (state === undefined) state = defaultState;

    if (sanityError) {
      throw sanityError;
    }

    var dirty = false;
    var finalState = finalReducers.map(function (reducer, key) {
      **var oldState = state.get(key); // This is where the error gets triggered**
      var newState = reducer(oldState, action);
      dirty = dirty || oldState !== newState;
      if (typeof newState === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error(getErrorMessage(key, action));
      }
      return newState;
    });

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      var warningMessage = getUnexpectedStateKeyWarningMessage(state, finalState, action);
      if (warningMessage) {
        console.error(warningMessage);
      }
    }

    return dirty ? finalState : state;
  };
}

module.exports = exports['default'];
```

Changing above to:

```
import { authStateReducer } from "redux-auth";
import Immutable from "immutable";

const auth = (state = {}, action) => {
  return authStateReducer(Immutable.fromJS(state), action);
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  auth,
  ...
});
```

seems to get rid of the error message & login action works fine. But the auth reducer doesn't receive any user data from the action.

Comment: I came across an issue report (little different then mine) but adding  

const auth = (state = {}, action) => {
  return authStateReducer(Immutable.fromJS(state), action);
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  ...
}); seems to get rid of the error message. I'm not exactly sure with its implications

Comment: You have to call `combineReducers` with an immutable map or otherwise it will just break. `Immutable.fromJS({
  routing: routerReducer,
  auth: authStateReducer,
  ....
})`, probably

Comment: Wouldn't this affect all of my reducers? All of my other reducers don't use immutable at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123373/discussion-between-dds-and-henry-h).

Comment: Hi @HenryH I tried to understand how to do that but failed. Can I use combineReducers from 'redux'? I am trying to do that, but I get an error while trying to map the immutable reducer's state. Can you explain what is the right way to do it? I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852422/combining-immutable-reducer-regular-reducer

Comment: Hi @DDS Please see my question to HenryH above. Can you help?